# Picture on Menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to put a "Home" picture on my following menu but it seems I'm not doing it the right way, because it appears a blank square.
(And I already tried using a .png and .jpg)

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menucss.css" media="screen">
        <ul>
            <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span><img src="Imgs/Home-icon.png"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href='shows.html'><span>Shows</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='blog.html'><span>Blog</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='loja.html'><span>Loja do Fã</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='faq.html'><span>Perguntas Frequentes</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: `.ico` files are used for favicons, and not images. What happens if you change it to a .jpg for example?

Comment: You are using `Iimgs/` and not `Imgs/`. Is the image url set properly?  You should also check if the photo was actually loaded.

Comment: You should change the `img` tag, and edit the CSS of `.active` using all the `background` properties as @Marco10 is telling you. Use only `img` tag when the image is content (something that CAN'T miss in the page), in this case, since home picture can be easily replaced with a "home" text, this is just for decoration

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the CSS for the class **active**, to include a background-image.

```
active
{
background-image:url("Iimgs/Home-icon.ico");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-size: 20px 20px; //here you put the size you want for the background
}
```

Not sure if you can use .ico files, but give it a try :)